# Python Matrix Multiplication - Append into empty list

Tags: python-3.x, matrix-multiplication

How do I generate random matrices and get them multiplied in an efficient way.

This is what I've done:

```
`mat1 = []
for i in range(0, order):
    num1 = random.sample(range(1,10), order)
    print(num1)
    mat1.append(num1)
print()

print("Result of Matrix Multiplication.")
for p in range(len(mat1)):
    for q in range(len(mat2[0])):
        for r in range(len(mat2)):
            res_matrix[p][q] += mat1[p][r] * mat2[r][q]
for res in res_matrix:

print(res)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to generate `res_matrix` using

```
res_matrix = [[0 for i in range(order)] for j in range(order)]
```

Also, have you heard of [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/)? It does this kind of computations (and many more) in an easy and very fast way. This is what your code would become with numpy

```
import numpy as np

print("Generate 1st Matrix")
mat1 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(order, order))
print(mat1)

print("Generate 2nd Matrix")
mat2 = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(order, order))
print(mat2)

res_matrix = mat1.dot(mat2)
print("Result of Matrix Multiplication.")
print(res_matrix)
```